# MongoDB Java client allowDiskUse does not work

Tags: java, mongodb, mongotemplate

I used the allowDiskUse option with the MongoTemplate :

```
AggregateIterable<Document> results = mongoTemplate.getCollection("match")
            .aggregate(...).allowDiskUse(true)
```

And still get this error :

> Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.

Is it bugged ?

Note that I use the mongo java client 3.11 and a mongo atlas M2 (v 4.2.9)

I also tried with batchSize and useCursor but it didn't work

Comment: Verify that it works with mongo shell and latest driver version.

Comment: I got the same error in the mongoshell. I tried with the db.runCommand(...) and with the db.getCollection("...").aggregate(...) command

Comment: Reference documentation where correct usage (for mongo shell) is described from the question, and ensure you are issuing the command in accordance with documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like that:

```
AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(new Aggregation(aggregationOperation1, aggregationOperation2, aggregationOperation3, ....).withOptions(AggregationOptions.Builder.allowDiskUse(true)), "match", Document.class);
```

Of course you must define you aggregation operations.

Comment: I tried and got the same error. I tried to run the command in the mongoshell directly and also got the same error.

Comment: Try to use the latest driver version.